# How to cross reference a third table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables in a MySQL 5.7 DB:

```
1. Search Result (100M+ rows)

SERP | ARTICLE_ID
1    | 88
2    | 99


2. Bundles (5k rows)

ARTICLE_ID | PRODUCT_ID
99         | 123
99         | 124


3. Product Catalog (1M rows)

PRODUCT_ID | NAME

123        | Bundle Product1
124        | Bundle Product2
88         | Native Product
```

Now the majority of items are native products and not bundles. However there are some bundles which are defined in the bundle table. This table references the belonging products in the product table. I do not know if a article_id is a bundle or a native product, only is it know if there is an entry within the bundles table.

Now I am looking to extend my extending query to also handle bundels if the article id is inside the bundle table.

Something like this:

```
SELECT mks.*
FROM serps mks
LEFT JOIN products p on mks.ARTICLE_ID = p.SKU

-- BUNDLE Recognition
LEFT JOIN bundles bun ON mks.ARTICLE_ID = bun.ARTICLE_ID
LEFT JOIN products bp ON bun.SKU = bp.SKU

WHERE p.somethign = 2 OR bp.somehting = 2
```

This also works but is slow:

```
FROM serps mks
LEFT JOIN bundles bun ON mks.ARTICLE_ID = bun.ARTICLE_ID -- BUNDLE Recognition
LEFT JOIN products p on bun.SKU = p.SKU OR mks.ARTICLE_ID = p.SKU
```

If I do seperate queries with the last leftjoin the result is returned within 300ms:

```
-- this returns native results only in 300ms
LEFT JOIN products p on mks.ARTICLE_ID = p.SKU

-- this returns bundles only in 200ms
LEFT JOIN products p on bun.SKU = p.SKU
```

The combination of both is what takes 5s.

Here is another approach:

```
FROM (
  SELECT SERP, ARTICLE_ID
    FROM merchants_keyword_serps
    AND DATE = 20210621
  UNION ALL
  SELECT mksi.SERP, bun.SKU AS ARTICLE_ID
    FROM serps mksi
    JOIN bundles bun ON mksi.ARTICLE_ID = bun.ARTICLE_ID
    AND mksi.DATE = 20210621
  ) mks
LEFT JOIN Maven360.manufacturers_products p on  mks.ARTICLE_ID = p.SKU
```

Each select takes 150ms but with UNION it takes seconds.

This is a very basic example, I am wonderig if there is something like a cross join or anything I do not think off that will allow the query to execute in an OK time < 500ms. At the moment the bundle integration lifts it from 200ms to 5s.

Comment: Did you add indexes on your fields?

Comment: Yes I did. There must be a smarter solution to add the bundel product ids to the search in case the article ID is matching the bundle article_id

Comment: @DavidBrossard I edited my question and added more detailed info.

Comment: `OR` is slow; `UNION` is sometimes the remedy.

Comment: @RickJames Please check my updated question. I added an approach with UNION. Similar result.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the 4 tables, plus `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` so we can further diagnose the issues.

Answer (score 0):

```
FROM (
  SELECT SERP, ARTICLE_ID
    FROM merchants_keyword_serps
    AND DATE = 20210621
  UNION ALL
  SELECT mksi.SERP, bun.SKU AS ARTICLE_ID
    FROM serps mksi
    JOIN bundles bun ON mksi.ARTICLE_ID = bun.ARTICLE_ID
    AND mksi.DATE = 20210621
  ) mks
LEFT JOIN Maven360.manufacturers_products p on  mks.ARTICLE_ID = p.SKU
```

Probably needs these:

```
merchants_keyword_serps:  INDEX(date)
serps:  INDEX(date, article_id)
bundles:  INDEX(article_id)
manufacturers_products:  INDEX(SKU)
```